# Unable read filename from form http post

Tags: javascript, form-post

var `origname` is not getting the filename. I want to read the value `RUNNING.txt`

> HTTP REQUEST Remote Address:192.168.2.17:9005 Request
>   URL:http://192.168.2.17:9005/upload Request Method:POST Status
>   Code:200 OK
>
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryAWVDAhOra67f0XeU Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="RUNNING.txt" Content-Type:
>   text/plain

### CODE

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
  var origname    = req.param("filename”)
```

;

Comment: That code suggests you are using a NodeJS HTTP library or web framework. Which one?

Comment: Using express js with gridfs-stream

Answer (score 0):

According to [this guide](http://howtonode.org/really-simple-file-uploads) you should be looking at:

```
req.files.file.name
```

Comment: files is undefined, so I get an error req.files.file.name and req.file.name both dont work

Comment: I did a lot of digging, found that bodyparsers are not supported in Express 4. SO tried using formidable npm but this isnt provided the result either

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using busboy. See https://github.com/mscdex/busboy
Express 4, no longer supports bodyparser, so don't waste time on it.

Thanks to busboy author for posting several other threads.

NOTE: You must use  req.pipe(busboy); This is there in github sample code